# Will I lose memory if the value of the field is NULL in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I set a `varchar` field with `size=200`. My question is that in MySQL, will I lose the memory on each new insertion to the database even if the field contain a null value? If it will be lost, is there any way to preserve them memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Leave that up to the database engine
2. No, you won't
3. It doesn't actually matter

The keyword is `dynamic rowsize`:  [Dynamic Table Characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dynamic-format.html)

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are varchar and mysql, no, you don't use those 200 chars when inserting a null.

However, this is a space issue, not a memory issue. It makes a big difference, because disk space is really cheap these days, so it doesn't make sense to optimize you architecture by means of trying to use less storage.

Quite the opposite, I'd rather define that field as char(200) and have up to 200 characters wasted on each row while in return the DB engine would know the exact offset in the storage just by counting the rows, thus saving time and cpu cycles, which are not cheap.